# Azure k8 API calls timeout

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have a problem with azure and it's kubernetes environment. Form to time calls to k8s API are failing and when it happened the pod which experiencing the issue stops responding (more like the network issue than application hanging), for a calls from other pods, but health check is working, so k8s is not restarting the pod. The only way to restore it is a deletion of the pod.

Here is a part of the stacktrace.

```
Failed to get list of services from DiscoveryClient org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient@7057dbda due to: {}
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [dev]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:602)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:63)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:253)
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.getServices(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:249)
.....
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:593)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:601)
```

What I know now:

- issue happens on azure
- doesn't depend on the load (also the actual calls are background jobs and they are also not depend on the load, so this is expected)
- doesn't depend on the number of services deployed or frequency of the calls to k8s API (so actual traffic to k8s API from cluster doesn't matter)
- it is very selective: if one service/replica is affected other can work without issues
- if affected pod is restarted quickly (we have a job to automate restarts) then problem tends to jump to other service

Azure support says it is problem with our apps, which are build on spring boot and it's auto discovery mechanism, but I am starting doubt it.

Basically it looks like pod is partially lost by k8s engine.

So the question is what is wrong and what else can I check?

Comment: id say this is, most likely, a fault in your app, since we are not observing anything like that. do you have repro steps? since you claim this is not specific to your app, it should be easy to reproduce. also, you don't even share your aks configuration